# Convert perl script to shell script: <STDIN> and chomp

Tags: shell, perl

Perl script line:

```
my $resp=<STDIN>;
chomp($resp);
```

Im trying to convert perl script to shell script... Just got stuck with this 2 lines... Please help me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just this:

```
read resp
```

In Perl [chomp](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) function is used to remove newline from the input.
The shell removes the newline automatically.